# Colorbox within HTTPS page

Tags: ssl, https, colorbox

I am trying to use colorbox within an HTTPS-page.
When I open colorbox, the page is not HTTPS any more because there are unsecured files being loaded...

Does anybody have a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Greetz,
  Mike

Answer (score 0):

if you're having the same issue as me, I managed to fix the problem by doing the following:

1. Open the following file `“jquery-colorbox.php”`
2. On line 45, replace the text `"WP_PLUGIN_URL"` with
   `"/wp-content/plugins/"`

   When finished, line 45 should look like:

   ```
   define('JQUERYCOLORBOX_PLUGIN_URL', '/wp-content/plugins/' .    
   JQUERYCOLORBOX_PLUGIN_NAME);
   ```

   Save and upload to your server, and you should be back in action.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your colorbox javascript file is being loaded with "http" instead of "https". So you need to review how it is being loaded and either change that or you can try using "//example.com/path/to/colorbox.js" (no http or https), in order to be available over ssl and non-ssl.